# How to center list of icons on a single line?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of icons that I want to display on one line. I keep getting icons left aligned but not centered on page. any ideas?

Here is my code

!-- List of Icons -->

```
<!-- Single Icon -->
<li class="overview animated entrance" data-appear-bottom-offset="100">
<!-- Feature List -->
    [tooltip] [ul class=feature-list] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Wireframing[/list-item] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Content Strategy[/list-item] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Information Architecture[/list-item] 
    [/ul] [/tooltip] 
 <!-- Icon --> 
 [icon-img name=ux title=UX][/icon-img]
 </li>

<!-- Single Icon -->
<li class="overview animated entrance" data-appear-bottom-offset="100">
<!-- Feature List -->
    [tooltip] [ul class=feature-list] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Cloud[/list-item] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Mobile Payment[/list-item] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]iBeacon[/list-item] 
    [/ul] [/tooltip] 
 <!-- Icon --> 
 [icon-img name=tech title=Tech][/icon-img]
 </li>


<!-- Single Icon -->
<li class="overview animated entrance" data-appear-bottom-offset="100">
<!-- Feature List -->
    [tooltip] [ul class=feature-list] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Facebook[/list-item] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Google +[/list-item] 
    [list-item spanclass=list-dot]Twitter[/list-item] 
    [/ul] [/tooltip] 
 <!-- Icon --> 
 [icon-img name=social title=Social][/icon-img]
 </li>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please put it in a FIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

Try to float icons to the left.

```
.overview, .animated, .entrance {
   float: left;
}
```

Or display icons as inline-blocks:

```
.overview, .animated, .entrance {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your ul in a div give width 100% to div and apply css rule text-align: center;
Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XUwd/1/)

```
text-align: center;
```

hope this will help you :)